# LINQ Group by and having where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Below is the SQL Query I am trying to translate

```
SELECT dbo.Contracts.Supplier 
FROM dbo.Contracts INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.Contracts.Product = dbo.Products.Product
where dbo.Products.ProductGroup='Crude'
GROUP BY dbo.Contracts.Supplier
```

Am I doing something wrong because I do not get same results with the following LINQ

```
     var result = from c in context.Contracts
                     join p in context.Products on c.Product equals p.Product1
                     where p.Product1.Equals("Crude")
                     group c by c.Supplier into g    
                     select new { supplier = g.Key  };
```

It is generating a weird statement

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Distinct1].[Supplier] AS [Supplier]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
[Extent1].[Supplier] AS [Supplier]
FROM [dbo].[Contracts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Crude' = [Extent1].[Product]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

Using distinct would work but to get same results, LINQ should be generating a statement like so (it's like it is ignoring the join):

```
SELECT distinct dbo.Contracts.Supplier 
FROM dbo.Contracts INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.Contracts.Product = dbo.Products.Product
where dbo.Products.ProductGroup='Crude'
```

Comment: If you're only interested in products where `p.Product1` is `"Product1"` why don't you filter that out *before* the grouping?

Comment: Wondering why you need grouping in this case.

Comment: We're converting an Access application to an ASP.NET MV3 web site (using entity framework as data layer) so the above query is generated from Access and I am just translating what was there! ... or at least trying to for now.

Comment: and the grouping by is to get a distinct list of supplier who supply that product and YES I change the where clause to filter before grouping, however same results.

Comment: Hm your LINQ query does not contain the identifier `ProductGroup`. Ist that ok? Shouldn't you be filtering on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using 'EntityFramework' or 'Linq To SQL'. If so, you should be able to use `navigation properties` to navigate to product and filter invalit results out. This way your query might look something like this:

```
var result = (from c in context.Contracts
              where c.Products.Any(p => p.ProductGroup == "Crude")
              select c.Supplier).Distinct();
```

It will automatically convert into correct query (in this case possibly without join even, just using `Exists` sql keyword) and return distinct suppliers. This is if I understand your objective correctly - you want to obtain all suppliers assigned to contracts that contain product from 'Crude' product group.

Basically you should try to avoid using `join`s from `linq to sql` or `linq to entities` as much as possible when you can use navigation properties. System will probably be better at converting them into specific `sql`.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake and I was using the wrong column, thank you for your second set of eyes! That was it....the where clause was on ProductGroup and not product. Oppps :)

Comment: I downloaded LINQPAD and that made it easier to troubleshoot